# expo doesnt start properly

Tags: react-native, expo

I tried to learn react native with expo in my first project so I created a project with the following cli commands:

```
npm i --location=global
expo init app
cd app
npm start
```

If im correct after running these commands a browser windows should open, redirected to metro bundler at `localhost:19000`. It didn't. The cli log:

> Starting Metro Bundler

> qr code here

> Metro waiting on exp://192.168.1.31:19000

> Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

> Press a │ open Android

> Press w │ open web

> Press r │ reload app

> Press m │ toggle menu

> Press ? │ show all commands

> Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.

Scanning the qr code or entering the ip into the app didnt connect - connection timed out.

How can I fix this?

Just in case you need it:

```
pc: windows 10
phone: android 9
node: v16.16.0
npm: 8.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

All i needed was to install the dependancies

```
npx expo install react-native-web@~0.18.7 react-dom@18.0.0 @expo/webpack-config@^0.17.0
```